# Wordpress widget missing from sidebar - only on some pages

Tags: wordpress

I am upgrading a friends wordpress site from 2.9.2 - 3.1    He uses the HTML Javascript Adder plugin to create a widget in a sidebar that disappears - but only on some pages.  Any idea what could cause this - or better yet how to fix it??

This didn't happen at all in 2.9.2.  In the course of the upgrade, the plugin was also upgraded...

Answer (score 2):

U treid to found that addon for 3.1 version of WordPress?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-javascript-adder/

Comment: Yes it says it is compatible up to 3.1, and it works fine on some pages.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved - looks like this was a plugin issue - I put the exact same code in a php block and now it displays on all pages like it is supposed to